# How do I concatenate the empty String to the beginning of a String in Matlab

Tags: matlab, string-concatenation, string

Say I typed `x = 'BODD'` into the command prompt of MATLAB and then said `x(1)` it would return `B`. What I want is `x(1)` to return the empty String (`''`) or nothing etc. and `x(2)` to return `B` and so forth up until `x(5)` returning the final `D`?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you mean that you really do want the *empty* zero-length string, `''`.  There have been some Answers to this question that assume that you meant that you wanted the one-character string that contains a space, ASCII value 32.

If that's the case, I'm afraid you can't to that - MATLAB arrays (including character arrays, which is all that a MATLAB "string" is) don't work that way.  There are two ways to look at it...

1. You asked for `x(1)`.  Now, the indexing expression that you used, `1`, has size `1x1`.  Therefore, you are guaranteed to get either a `1x1` return value, OR an error.  That means that there's *no way* to get a `0x1` or `0x0` (the true "empty string"). This is similar to the way that, if you had asked for `x(2:4)`, you would be guaranteed to get a `1x3` array of characters back.  In that case, `2:4` is a `1x3` array.
2. There's no way to "meaningfully" prepend a zero-length string to the beginning of another string.  If `a = 'WXYZ';`, then running `b = ['' a]` just returns `'WXYZ'` back.  It didn't somehow stick a magical placeholder for an empty string at the front of the original string.

Answer (score 0):

You can't concatenate `''` at end or beginning

However, you can have blank/space, like this :-

```
>> x=BODD;
>> x=[' ' x]; % Use normal matrix concatenation
>> x(1)

ans =

>> x(2)

ans =

B
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following concatenation

```
x = [' ' x];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the string itself to still be 'BODD', you could try writing a custom function:

```
function [char] = emptyConcat(string, index)

if (index == 1)
     char = '';
else
     char = string(index - 1);
```